# How to make value to be unique scope in two ng-repeat in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

There are two ng-repeat one inside another ( Parent and child). Parent is creating well with unique scope but child is not creating with unique scope. it's just duplicating same scope values. I have created simple fiddle. Please help anyone to archive this.

HTML Code:

```
 <div ng-app>
  <h2>Todo</h2>
  <div ng-controller="serviceCtrl">

    <ul class="unstyled">
      <li ng-repeat="serviceTemp in serviceTemplateCode.serviceTemplates">
         <input type="text" placeholder="e.g. https://stream.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/filter.json" ng-model='serviceTemp.url'> {{serviceTemp.url}}
         <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="serviceParam in serviceTemplateCode.serviceParameters">
                 <input type="text" placeholder="param" ng-model='serviceParam.param'> {{serviceParam.param}}
                  <button ng-click='addParameter()'>
           addParam
           </button>
        </li>
         </ul>
```

Angular JS Code:

```
function serviceCtrl($scope) {
 $scope.serviceTemplateCode = {};
 $scope.serviceTemplateCode.serviceTemplates = [];
 $scope.serviceTemplateCode.serviceParameters = [];
   $scope.serviceTemplateCode.serviceTemplates.push({});
  $scope.serviceTemplateCode.serviceParameters.push({});

 $scope.addTemplate = function() {
         $scope.serviceTemplateCode.serviceTemplates.push({});
 };

  $scope.addParameter = function() {
      $scope.serviceTemplateCode.serviceParameters.push({});
 };

}
```

Fiddle Link : http://jsfiddle.net/bagya1985/u0av852q/4/

Comment: please don't put your question as code to pass the question form validation, fiddle links must be accompanied by some code, please add a minimal and verifiable example here.

Comment: @Kaddath sorry by mistake i have done. can you please revert my reputation points.

Comment: No, problem, we all make mistakes, i'll remove the downvote as soon as your question is edited :)

Comment: @Kaddath - I'm not getting any reply from any one. can you please revert .

Comment: The vote is most probably not the cause you don't get replies, but the question itself and the way it's formatted. More than that, it's common not to have an answer right away in a minute, a bit of patience is always good. If you like, i remove the vote even if you didn't edit, but that won't cause a reply rush.. i didn't even click on the link because the way the question as formatted, lots of people would do like me i bet.

Comment: Well i don't write this as an answer, because there are things not clear about your code and question might also be closed, but consider [this updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xbwd0y6k/1/): it seems that the `ng-model` was in error because there was no `param` property in `serviceParam` elements to bind with. You notice that your code duplicates the params for all templates at once, I think that what you'd want is that `serviceParameters` are inside each `serviceTemplates` and your second `ng-repeat` would be on `serviceTemp.serviceParameters` instead, but that's just a guess..

Comment: @Kaddath - It's not need to give while creating scope.please look at parent ng-repeat scope.. in that also i have binded 'url' . It's working fine.

Comment: my bad, it was actually the `| serviceParam track by $index` which was the guilty one. But definetly better if you also add the properties you want to bind with. If you have other questions/problems, please consider updating the question, and add some code to it ;)